# Meaning of 'commit' and subject of 'sustainable' in following context?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I read this article in the NY Times. [Europe and the U.S. Make Ambitious Plans to Reduce Reliance on Russian Gas](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/25/business/energy-environment/biden-eu-liquefied-natural-gas-deal-russia.html)

> Environmentalists criticized Mr. Biden’s announcement because they fear it will **commit** the United States and Europe to using fossil fuels for decades longer than **they argue is sustainable** given the growing toll of climate change.

1. I looked it up in the dictionary, but I still did not understand the meaning of 'commit' exactly. Does it means 'promise'?
2. What is the subject of 'sustainable'? Why is an 'is' attached to 'they argue'? I did not understand the structure of the sentence.

I use the Collins dictionary: [commit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/commit).

Comment: Does it help if you just delete _they argue_ and then try to see the structure? It usually helps if you link to the dictionary you used so people can point you to the right definition there.

Comment: it looks like in your dictionary, this "commit" would fit definition #4: agree to do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonyms for "commit" in the sentence in the question are bind, obligate, force, require.

"They argue" in this context means essentially "claim" or "try to persuade that". It is a little clearer if you turn it around:

Environmentalists argue (claim) that using fossil fuels for decades is not sustainable (unharmful) because it causes climate change, which is getting worse.